# GCC mod() definition

Tags: c++, function, gcc

I was making faster mod(x,2) function in C++ with GCC (compiled using -O3 -ffast-math) and bumped to difference in results between GCC and Octave:

```
float fast_fmod2(float x){ // over 50x faster than std::fmod(x, 2.0f)
    x *= 0.5f;
    return 2.0f * ( x - std::floor(x));
}
```

Result (mod(input,2.0f)):

```
Input       : -7.8539786 
std::fmod()  : -1.853978633881
Octave mod(): 0.146021366119
fast_fmod2  : 0.146021366119
...
Input       : 7.8539805
std::fmod()  : 1.853980541229
Octave mod(): 1.853980541229
fast_fmod2  : 1.853980541229
```

I checked couple other math software as well and it looks like at least Sollya and Wolfram|Alpha supports Octave results and before mentioned documented same definition for the function as Octave did.

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MOD.html) defines mod function as:

```
mod(A, P) = A - (int(A/P) * P)
```

[Sollya](https://www.sollya.org/sollya-7.0/help.php?name=modeucl) and [Octave](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/mod.html) defines as:

```
mod(a, b) = a - (b * floor(a / b))
```

Because of int(a/b) rounds differently compared to floor(a/b), GCC definition gives different answer for negative A's.

```
>> int16(-2.19/2)
ans = -1
>> floor(-2.19/2)
ans = -2
```

Is it a bug in GCC version or something else behind the difference?

Comment: `Result:` what does this "result" represent? `GCC defines mod function as:` `Sollya and Octave defines as:` Could you give references for that?

Comment: Octave and C++ are different languages, so they can have different definitions of `mod`.  There is no reason to believe the GCC C++ toolchain has a bug just because it is different from some other language.  Also, what specific function are you worried about and can you provide a link to it or some sample code that uses it (a complete compilable program, including all the needed headers)?  I can't find `std::mod` in the C++ standard.

Comment: This is interesting `std::fmod` [gcc is infarct much slower](https://quick-bench.com/q/xVf2hLL34-SlAkSWTNby2D5eSQ4), but [for clang there is no difference](https://quick-bench.com/q/scgZR3bJyY2rVsQFgq0EtB9URmI).

Comment: @MarekR, `float fast_mod_ab(float a, float b){return a - (b * floor(a / b));}` is too faster than std::fmod(a,b) (when compiled in gcc using -O3 -ffast-math).

Comment: @JuhaP I didn't check assembly and this test doesn't measure what it suppose to. Sorry about that. Optimizer has removed your function. Here is [fixed version](https://quick-bench.com/q/k2-RlFCYG-g0Byt1PwHCH8ssqBo) now your function is the slowest (but close to `std::remainder`). This is prove how hard and treacherous are performance measurements in C/C++. For some strange reason initial version of test doesn't compile on godbolt.

Comment: @MarekR, do you mean that with -ffast-math, the divisor is constant and the function inlined or what you mean by "removed"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean [`std:fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) instead of `std::mod` (there's no `std::mod` in the official c++ standard)

The reason for this difference is that [`std::fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) doesn't do what you think it does.

[`std::fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) calculates the remainder and **not** the arithmetic modulus.

> Computes the floating-point remainder of the division operation `x`/`y`

If you want the arithmetic modulus you need to use [`std::remainder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/remainder) instead:

> Computes the IEEE remainder of the floating point division operation `x`/`y` .
> The IEEE floating-point remainder of the division operation `x/y` calculated by this function is exactly the value `x - n*y`, where the value `n` is the integral value nearest the exact value `x/y`. When `|n-x/y| = ½`, the value `n` is chosen to be even.

This will produce the expected result in your example:

```cpp
std::cout << std::remainder(-7.8539786f, 2.0f) << std::endl; // 0.146021
```

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/1h74TEvdc)

---

So to answer your question: This is  not a bug, this is intended behaviour.
The functions are just named differently in C++ (albeit with a slighly confusing naming scheme)

- Octave [`mod`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/mod.html) == C++ [`std::reminder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/remainder)
- Octave [`rem`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/rem.html) == C++ [`std::fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)

Comment: Yes, std::fmod in question.

Comment: So, it's different purpose even similar function naming in question. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @JuhaP yes, exactly :) `std::fmod` does the equivalent of `rem` in octave, while `std::reminder` would be the equivalent for `mod` in octave.

Comment: Performance comparison of `fast_fmod2`  vs `std::fmod` and `std::remainder` on [gcc](https://quick-bench.com/q/vnGXUlDY57Ni1beuvG6xhQbNRlc) vs [clang](https://quick-bench.com/q/sK07Q2l5eTJ4QRUwmOKVBW-fPz8)

Comment: @MarekR there's a small problem in that comparison - both gcc and clang managed to completely remove the call to `fast_fmod2` so the test case for it is just a noop (it's timing is also equal to the quickbench noop bar) [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E4eE4xq6E)

Comment: Here's a fairer comparison: [gcc](https://quick-bench.com/q/0aV7so0fJEb--qEFDzd4BuYoiRc) - [clang](https://quick-bench.com/q/py9di3gU64gz_73wY7ZQT0V4x2Q). So in gcc it's about equal with `std::remainder`, in clang it's a bit faster (7x) than `std::remainder`.

Comment: I use this benchmark - https://godbolt.org/z/b7sdaonzj (read the note from benchmark author).

Comment: Does Quick-bench omit -ffast-math switch (only -O3 shows there) ... as it has clear impact on std library function performance.

Comment: With `-ffast-math`: [gcc](https://quick-bench.com/q/AkObaN_dWQBzIEcd9EaKdfhH_PU) - [clang](https://quick-bench.com/q/iXSYbJdlYD4XCmZx6l0Vpw93Fbo) .

Comment: @Turtlefight I was to lazy to inspect assembly :(, Sorry about that, [this is better](https://quick-bench.com/q/k2-RlFCYG-g0Byt1PwHCH8ssqBo) and shows that OP approach is the slowest. It is strange that my first version of test doesn't compile on godbolt and [documentation of google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md#templated-benchmarks) says it should.

Comment: @MarekR I ran into that problem as well, that's why i replaced the templated test function with 3 individual ones in my benchmarks. not sure why it compiles without issues for quickbench but not on godbolt. @JuhaP also please keep in mind that `std::remainder` does a few extra things that your `fast_fmod2` function does not - mainly the special handling & guarantees for 0, Infinity and NaN. [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder)

Comment: @Turtlefight, do you mean that with -ffast-math, the divisor is constant and the function inlined or what you mean by "removed"?

Comment: @JuhaP there are no instructions left - both gcc & clang were smart enough to prove that the result of `fast_fmod2` is unused and therefore completely removed the call. Essentially the benchmark tested the performance of an empty loop (`for (auto _ : state) { /* NOTHING */ }`) - which of course is a lot faster than the standard functions :) - you can see this in the disassembly ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E4eE4xq6E)): notice how `MessureModFast` doesn't contain ANY floating point operations - it literally just calls `StartKeepRunning()` followed by `FinishKeepRunning()`.

Comment: @Turtlefight, here's the other function (in comments below question) tested - https://quick-bench.com/q/NB9AUf4unxMIu55qZeYbACNjsU0  ... does it suffer same? https://quick-bench.com/q/r-oeO3PcShdbBHS2RUI8dgVpXRw

Comment: The first [linked benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/NB9AUf4unxMIu55qZeYbACNjsU0) has that exact problem - the second one is fine. Those are the correct ones: Without fastmath: [gcc](https://quick-bench.com/q/0aV7so0fJEb--qEFDzd4BuYoiRc) - [clang](https://quick-bench.com/q/py9di3gU64gz_73wY7ZQT0V4x2Q) / with fastmath: [gcc](https://quick-bench.com/q/AkObaN_dWQBzIEcd9EaKdfhH_PU) - [clang](https://quick-bench.com/q/iXSYbJdlYD4XCmZx6l0Vpw93Fbo)

Comment: @Turtlefight, your test run "gcc w/ fastmath" has an additional double to float conversion which affects ~35 in CPU time value ... so, it's actually 2.9x faster than std::fmod and 4.3x  faster than std::remainder. Just wondering why -ffast-math switch slower the library functions that much but improves the 'customized' function (by CPU-time values)?